# How to remove selection after multiple clicks?

Tags: javascript, selection

I have some div with onclick event. After clicks in this element text from inside gets mark (selection).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNyAl.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/baB0E.jpg
How can I remove this?

Answer (score 2):

This is easily solvable with CSS:

```
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Then add the `noselect` class to the elements you don't want to be selectable.